# No key defined. Define the key for this EntityType when implementing interface that has Id

Tags: ef-code-first, xaf

I want to implement an interface defined in Dev Express IResource in my EF Code First business object.

```
public class JResource : IResource , IXafEntityObject
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdKey { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]   
        public object Id => IdKey;  // since IResource wants this.
        // other properties
    }
```

When I run my application to create the database I get an error that I need to define the key for this EntityType.

I think the problem is that EF wants to regard Id as the Key but I have made Id NotMapped since I want it to be an Int and the interface wants it to be an object.

Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I was using the wrong reference for the [Key] attribute.
The correct one is

```
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute
```